# What's the usage of the file named "conf/masters" in Flink?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-flink

Since we can specify a master by "jobmanager.rpc.address" in "flink-conf.yaml" ,what's the usage of the file named"conf/masters"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used for starting standalone cluster with HA mode.

You can check out more [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/jobmanager_high_availability.html#masters-file-masters)